# MAMP stopped working after last minor OSX update

Tags: wordpress, macos, mamp

After a minor OSX update (security and some other things on 10.8.5), MAMP stopped working correctly. While PHP is still running normally (my PHP sites are loading OK), there is a serious problem with MySQL (using WordPress).

When I try to login to an existing WP, the login screen only refreshes itself - nothing happens and there is no error.

I then went to install a fresh WP with the standard install procedure but I received "ERROR: "Table Prefix" must not be empty." when prompted to enter db user/pass. Then I manually added credentials to config file but then on the next step received an error "Please provide a valid Username.".

I reinstalled MAMP to the latest version and rebooted OSX but it's the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably belongs on SuperUser but nonetheless - What happens when you visit the phpMyAdmin page?

Comment: phpMyAdmin normally works. I've also been able to add the database normally. It does however have red question mark icons on all databases [?].

Comment: You might find that the MySQL version has been updated either that or the privileges table has been wiped (if you've created specific users). Check both!

Comment: I'm not that knowledgeable in phpmyadmin. I did find USER_PRIVILEGES table in information_schema database. Unfortunately I don't know how to check if MySQL has been updated. Although I removed and then freshly installed MAMP so I would expect this would be resolved?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Answer your own question with what you've done to solve it that way anyone else that stumbles across this question can see the answer. You're welcome (and welcome to SO)!

Comment: Oops, looks like I wasn't clear - I did not solve it. I freshly installed MAMP before asking a question here. I was referring to your question that the MySQL might have been updated and that this shouldn't be an issue if I did a fresh install. Sorry for the confusion.